# How do I query time data type with between 2 times varying over midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I query time data type with between 2 times varying over midnight.
Here is what I have tried.

```
declare @timeValue time
SET @timeValue = '23:30:00'

SELECT @timeValue,DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue),DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue)
WHERE @timeValue BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue) AND DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue)
```

But if we take the above example for finding if the time is valid in between 30 mins before and after, and it it varies over midnight. I don't get expected result.

Expected result would be the row with value in timeValue variable along with 30 mins before and after as other columns.

But if I use the time which is not crossing over the midnight like the one below it works properly.

```
declare @timeValue time
SET @timeValue = '23:00:00'

SELECT @timeValue,DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue),DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue)
WHERE @timeValue BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue) AND DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue)
```

And I get the following response as expected.

---

23:00:00.0000000 22:30:00.0000000 23:30:00.0000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time wraps at midnight. In other words: `23:30 + 00:30 = 00:00` which is less than `23:30`. Condition `23:00 < 23:30 < 00:00` is not met. Workaround is to convert arguments to datetime:

```
declare @timeValue time
SET @timeValue = '23:30:00'

SELECT @timeValue,DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue),DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue)
WHERE CONVERT(datetime,@timeValue) BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -30, CONVERT(datetime,@timeValue)) AND DATEADD(minute, +30, CONVERT(datetime,@timeValue))
```

Comment: Valid Answer Pawel. Thanks for Response.

Answer (score 1):

This is Because the `TIME` data type doesn't have a date component to it.  you will need to use `DATETIME` or one of the other date date types that have a time component.  Without the date your time is not between those 2 times.

```
declare @timeValue DATETIME
SET @timeValue = '23:30:00'

SELECT @timeValue,DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue),DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue)
WHERE @timeValue BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue) AND DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue)
```

Comment: Valid Answer Matt.. Thanks for Response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the help of a `CASE` statement. If the time value moves to next day ,set the maximum limit as '23:59' .

```
declare @timeValue1 time
SET @timeValue1 = '23:45:00'

SELECT @timeValue1,DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue1),DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue1)
WHERE @timeValue1 BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -30, @timeValue1) 
     AND case WHEN(DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue1))<@timeValue1 THEN '23:59:59.9999999' ELSE (DATEADD(minute, +30, @timeValue1)) END
```

**Output :** 
[image]

Comment: Valid Answer Unnikrishnan. Thanks for Response.

Answer (score 0):

I am not doing anything complex.  Nor have I tested every scenario, but the following table and simple query do what I need thus far.

```
| zone | days    | start    | stop     |
+------+---------+----------+----------+
|    1 | 1234567 | 05:00:00 | 17:59:59 |
|    2 | 1234567 | 05:00:00 | 17:59:59 |
|    3 | 1234567 | 05:00:00 | 17:59:59 |
|    1 | 1234567 | 18:00:00 | 04:59:59 |
|    2 | 1234567 | 18:00:00 | 04:59:59 |
|    3 | 1234567 | 18:00:00 | 04:59:59 |
```

---

```
SELECT days,start,stop,
IF(stop < start,
      ( IF(('04:55:00' BETWEEN start AND '24:00:00') OR 
         ('04:55:00' BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND stop), 'y', 'n') ),
         ( IF('04:55:00' BETWEEN start AND stop, 'y', 'n') )
      ) AS z FROM temp_settings_plans_details HAVING z='y'
```

`04:55:00` is the input.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it directly answer's the OP's question, just solves a similar task